# select from multiple tables but ordering by a datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that are unrelated (related that each contains data for a different social network). Each has a datetime field dated- I'm already grouping by hour as you can see below (this one below for linked_in)

```
SELECT count(*), date_format(dated, '%Y:%m:%d %H') as hour
FROM upd8r_linked_in_accts
WHERE CAST(dated AS DATE) = '".$start_date."'
GROUP BY hour
```

I would like to know how to do a total across all 3 networks- the tables for the three are

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upd8r_facebook_accts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fb_id` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `dated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=80 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upd8r_linked_in_accts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `linked_in` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `oauth_secret` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `first_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `second_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=200 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upd8r_twitter_accts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `twitter` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `twitter_secret` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

something like this ?

```
(SELECT count(*), date_format(dated, '%Y:%m:%d %H') as hour
 FROM upd8r_linked_in_accts 
 WHERE CAST(dated AS DATE) = '".$start_date."')
UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*), date_format(dated, '%Y:%m:%d %H') as hour
 FROM upd8r_facebook_accts
 WHERE CAST(dated AS DATE) = '".$start_date."')
UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*), date_format(dated, '%Y:%m:%d %H') as hour 
 FROM upd8r_twitter_accts 
 WHERE CAST(dated AS DATE) = '".$start_date."')
UNION ALL
GROUP BY hour
```

**update**

the data in the actual database is not related by any pk or fk but the data is related that each table represents a user registering for a social network through the application and therefore i need to show the amount of users registered per hour across all three tables

**update 2**

the output of the query should show %Y:%m:%d %H and the amount of users registered (records created) that hour across the three tables.. each hour returning a new row (ordered by the time)

Comment: Can you add an example data and result, i didnt get what u need and how related data

Comment: What's your current situation? Does it work? Is there an error? Does it not yield what you want? What else have you tried?

Comment: the data is unrelated- i will update the question

Comment: the union gives an error with the query listed in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to the solution

```
select t1.hourx, sum(t1.column1)
from (
  (
    SELECT count(*) as column1, date_format(dated, '%Y:%m:%d %H') as hourx 
    FROM upd8r_linked_in_accts 
    WHERE CAST(dated AS DATE) = '".$start_date."'
    GROUP BY hourx 
  ) 
  UNION ALL 
  (
    SELECT count(*) as column1, date_format(dated, '%Y:%m:%d %H') as hourx 
    FROM upd8r_facebook_accts 
    WHERE CAST(dated AS DATE) = '".$start_date."'
    GROUP BY hourx
  ) 
  UNION ALL 
  (
    SELECT count(*) as column1, date_format(dated, '%Y:%m:%d %H') as hourx
    FROM upd8r_twitter_accts 
    WHERE CAST(dated AS DATE) = '".$start_date."'
    GROUP BY hourx
  ) 
) t1
GROUP BY t1.hourx
```

I use 'hourx' to avoid reserve words, maybe not necessary.

I hope this works.

**[ADD]** This solution is called 'inline view'. You can google for that. It is supported by most of databases (mysql, oracle mssql and etc)

Comment: the output of the query should show %Y:%m:%d %H and the amount of users registered (records created) that hour across the three tables.. each hour returning a new row (ordered by the time)

Comment: this returns two rows- one with hour = null and sum(t1.column1) = 0 and another row with hour = 2011:11:20 17 and  with a sum(t1.column1) =146

Comment: i think i have gotten it- i added group by into the subqueries- maybe this might work..?

Comment: Yes, you and I miss that group by in the subqueries. :)